# How to delete group items from expandableListview?

Tags: android

I have an app which contain expandableListview with some child data. I want to delete group but cannot able to do. Please provide concurrent solution.

code:-

```
 // Listview Group expanded listener
    expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            Log.e(TAG,"expandPostion::"+whiteListModels.get(groupPosition));
        }
    });
    // Listview Group collasped listener
    expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
            Log.e(TAG,"collapsePostion::"+whiteListModels.get(groupPosition));


        }
    });
```

Comment: delete group from list and then call notifiDataSetChanged

Comment: You defined your groups in an array. Just remove the group from the array.

Comment: How........please send some code snap

Comment: Or define a new array or list.

Comment: post ur adapter code then it would be good to guide you

Answer (score 0):

Remove group data from `ArrayList`, on click of delete button then call `notifyDataSetChanged`, It will work.

```
btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               whiteListModels.remove(groupPosition);
               //Adapter attached to expListView
               Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```